# How to get number of slot in a VueJS component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, slot

I need my component to get slots number are occupied by the parent component
For example:

This is the component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot/>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  name: 'comp',
  data() {
    return {
      nslot: 0
    }
  }
</script>
```

This is the parent

```
<template>
  <div>
    <component>
      <button slot=""></button>
      <button slot=""></button>
      <button slot=""></button>
      <button slot=""></button>
      ...
    <component/>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  name: 'comp'
</script>
```

How i can do? I want to get number of used slot in the "nslot" variable

I prefer using method, (in the component) like:

```
mounthed() {
  this.nslot = this.getslotnumber()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [scoped slot](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#scoped-slots) like :

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <slot :nslot="nslot" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  name: 'comp',
  data() {
    return {
      nslot: 0
    }
  }
</script>
```

in parent :

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <compt v-slot="{nslot}">
      <button :slot="nslot">{{nslot}}</button>
    <comp/>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  name: 'comp'
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, but i'm looking for other method, like: mounthed() { this.nslot = this.getslotnumber() }